# How can you trigger the reload of firefox on file save?

Tags: firefox, frontend, backend

I'm curious with all the webservers reloading the code on save, can't we just make firefox do the same when in develop mode? any hints on how to do this?

Comment: For what it's worth, I was unable to understand what you're asking. What is "the code"?

Comment: sorry, now wthat I read that back I notice it's out of context. by "the code" I was referring to the backend servers for python most have a "code reload" feature that will refresh the running code when they detect a file change.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout out xrefresh. I know a lot of guys who use css compilers and like this tools.

http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/